The name of a subject
What is the study of the root of a subject called? i.e. that tells where the rules of that subject come from, how they were made, who made them, etc.
I guess morphology, etymology, philology, none are the ones that I need to know the name of.

It's not clear what you are asking. Can you give an example of how you want to use this word?

I need to know the subject name.

The subject teaching bio is called biology, the subject teaching belief is called theology, the subject teaching the root of a language is entomology, and the subject studying fossils is called palaeontology, what about the subject that teaches the root of the principles of anything?

Etymology, not entomology.

When you say "a subject" do you mean "any subject"?  E.g. How did phrenology get its start?  And you want to know the name for the subject where such questions are posed and answered?  Your question is not at all clear.

Entomology is the study of insects.

OP's query:

What is the study of the root of a subject called? i.e., that tells where the rules of that subject come from, how they were made, who made them, etc.

There isn't a single term that precisely captures all aspects of your question. However, you can use:

"Philosophy" of something
"History" of something
"Epistemology"

These terms help explore where the rules of a subject come from, how they were made, and who created them.

Philosophy.
is the study of fundamental concepts and principles underlying any field, often addressing the nature and structure of those principles. It investigates the origin of knowledge and the justification of beliefs.


History.
examines the development of a subject over time, focusing on how its principles evolved and who contributed to their formation.
For example:

History of science explores how scientific rules developed.
History of philosophy tracks the formation and evolution of philosophical ideas and methods.
History of language investigates the evolution of linguistic rules.



Epistemology.
is the branch of philosophy concerned with the nature, origin, and limits of knowledge. It looks at how knowledge is formed and justified, which is closely related to how the rules of a discipline come to be.


"history of" would be my answer.

@JamesK I thought the question asked for many things so one word can't describe it. I always find your comments/ answers valuable.
